# Image width 100%, no horizontal scroll

Tags: css, image, scrollbar

I have an image set to 100% width, which is working correctly. However, the image produces a horizontal scroll bar equal to the full width of the image (1366 in this case). I've tried `overflow:hidden;` but it's doing nothing. How do I kill the extra white space/horizontal scroll bar? Thanks.

```
.header-image-inner img {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

<div class="header-image-inner">
    <img width="1366" height="422" alt="banner" src="http://216.227.216.66/~mercantileportag/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Home_BannerImage1.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Apply overflow to the parent div (not to image) or add width: 1366px to img in CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overflow needs to be applied to the container element, not the element itself. For example:

```
.header-image-inner{
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header-image-inner img {
    width: 100%;
}
```